# Detailed errors in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, web

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting 500 errors in setting up a website in IIS.

So far I've tried the following steps:

- Enabled Failed Request Tracing (Doesn't write logs for this site, but
  works for other sites)
- Enabled detailed error messages. Still Getting the default 500 page
  with no additional information.
- Give app pool full permission to the project directory.
- Made sure app pool was running on classic .NET 2 (old app)
- Running the site under a permutation of (Classic/Integrated, .NET
  2/4)
- Enabled anonymous authentication

So my thinking is, somehow, the site fails before the logging modules are ran.

I suspect this is the case because I see no new entities in Event Viewer, IIS Advanced Logs folder, Or in Failed Request Tracing folder. My only source of information (besides 500 error) is a new entry in the IIS log:

```
2012-12-04 13:06:05 127.0.0.7 GET / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;.....)
```

To verify this, is there a way to check which stage of the pipeline a request failed? Is it possible to run the logging modules before the failure occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [trace event logger for HTTP.sys](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace.aspx). With this you can determine if the request is even making it to the right app pool in IIS. [Direction on usage](http://helephant.com/2012/07/23/debugging-iis7-requests-with-windows-event-tracing/)

As a last resort, Microsoft offers a tool called [Debug Diagnostic](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798). When you have no other option, use this. It will produce a crash dump of the app pool of your choice. Not easy to go through, but it’s a lead. [Direction on usage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789)